# PowerShell Get-Service is very slow to return results

Tags: powershell

I have tried several methods for gathering service data and I can't seem to get one to meet all my needs. `Get-Service` works fine but is very slow when I pipe in a couple `Where-Object` properties. `Get-CimInstance` is much faster but I can't figure out how to exclude services. Any ideas?

Here's my code attempts so far. This one is fast until I add the `Where-Object`. Then it takes 3 times longer if I do:

```
Get-Service -DisplayName * -ComputerName $Name -Exclude $ExcludedServices | Where-Object { $_.status -eq 'Running' -or $_.StartType -eq 'Automatic' }
```

This one works much faster but I don't know how to exclude a list of Services if needed:

```
Get-CimInstance -ClassName Win32_Service -ComputerName $Name | Where-Object { $_.state -eq 'Running' -or $_.StartMode -eq 'Auto' }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I don't know how to exclude a list of Services if needed

[`Get-CimInstance`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/cimcmdlets/get-ciminstance?view=powershell-6) allows you to impose a [WQL WHERE clause](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394054(v=vs.85).aspx) constraint on the query:

```
Get-CimInstance Win32_Service -Filter 'Name != "excludedSvc"'
```

You can also restrict the items based on the `State` or `StartMode` properties inside the query, so the remote computer doesn't have to send back all of the services:

```
Get-CimInstance Win32_Service -Filter 'Name != "excludedSvc" AND State = "Running" AND StartMode = "Auto"'
```

Comment: This does work for me. But how would I exclude multiple services instead of just one... I can't seem to find any working examples online.

Comment: Ah, I was using OR instead of AND. Thank you!